# Is normalization always necessary and more efficient?

Tags: database, database-design, database-normalization

I got into databases and normalization. I am still trying to understand normalization and I am confused about its usage. I'll try to explain it with this example.
Every day I collect data which would look like this in a single table:

**TABLE: CAR_ALL**

| ID | DATE | CAR | LOCATION | FUEL | FUEL_USAGE | MILES | BATTERY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 01.01.2021 | Toyota | New York | 40.3 | 3.6 | 79321 | 78 |
| 520 | 01.01.2021 | BMW | Frankfurt | 34.2 | 4.3 | 123232 | 30 |
| 934 | 01.01.2021 | Mercedes | London | 12.7 | 4.7 | 4321 | 89 |
| 123 | 05.01.2021 | Toyota | New York | 34.5 | 3.3 | 79515 | 77 |
| 520 | 05.01.2021 | BMW | Frankfurt | 20.1 | 4.6 | 123489 | 29 |
| 934 | 05.01.2021 | Mercedes | London | 43.7 | 5.0 | 4400 | 89 |

In this example I get data for thousands of cars every day. ID, CAR and LOCATION never changes. All the other data can have other values daily. If I understood correctly, normalizing would make it look like this:

**TABLE: CAR_CONSTANT**

| ID | CAR | LOCATION |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Toyota | New York |
| 520 | BMW | Frankfurt |
| 934 | Mercedes | London |

**TABLE: CAR_MEASUREMENT**

| GUID | ID | DATE | FUEL | FUEL_USAGE | MILES | BATTERY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 01.01.2021 | 40.3 | 3.6 | 79321 | 78 |
| 2 | 520 | 01.01.2021 | 34.2 | 4.3 | 123232 | 30 |
| 3 | 934 | 01.01.2021 | 12.7 | 4.7 | 4321 | 89 |
| 4 | 123 | 05.01.2021 | 34.5 | 3.3 | 79515 | 77 |
| 5 | 520 | 05.01.2021 | 20.1 | 4.6 | 123489 | 29 |
| 6 | 934 | 05.01.2021 | 43.7 | 5.0 | 4400 | 89 |

I have two questions:

1. Does it make sense to create an extra table for DATE?
2. It is possible that new cars will be included through the collected data.
   For every row I insert into `CAR_MEASUREMENT`, I would have to check whether the ID is already in `CAR_CONSTANT`. If it doesn't exist, I'd have to insert it.
   But that means that I would have to check through `CAR_CONSTANT` thousands of times every day. Wouldn't it be more efficient if I just insert the whole data as 1 row into `CAR_ALL`? I wouldn't have to check through `CAR_CONSTANT` every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The benefits of normalization are dependent on your specific use case. I can see both pros and cons to normalizing your schema, but its impossible to say which is better without more knowledge of your use case.

**Pros:**

- With your schema, normalization could reduce the amount of data consumed by your DB since CAR_MEASUREMENT will probably be much larger than CAR_CONSTANT. This scales up if you are able to factor out additional data into CAR_CONSTANT.
- Normalization could also improve data consistency if you ever begin tracking additional fixed data about a car, such as license plate number. You could simply update one row in CAR_CONSTANT instead of potentially thousands of rows in CAR_ALL.
- A normalized data structure *can* make it easier to query data for a specific car. using a LEFT JOIN, the DBMS can search through the CAR_MEASUREMENT table based on the integer ID column instead of having to compare two string columns.

**Cons:**

- As you noted, the normalized form requires an additional lookup and possible insert to CAR_CONSTANT for every addition to CAR_MEASUREMENT. Depending on how fast you are collecting this data, those extra queries could be too much overhead.

To answer your questions directly:

1. I would not create an extra table for just the date. The date is a part of the CAR_MEASUREMENT data and should not be separated. The only exception that I can think of to this is if you will eventually collect measurements that do not contain any car data. In that case, then it would make sense to split CAR_MEASUREMENT into separate MEASUREMENT and CAR_DATA tables with MEASUREMENT containing the date, and CAR_DATA containing just the car-specific data.
2. See above. If you have a use case to query data for a specific car, then the normalized form can be more efficient. If not, then the additional INSERT overhead may not be worth it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In this use case, I would query and map the daily car information to a chart and world map. Since I will mostly query by DATE (and not by specific car), I guess a normalization would be unnecessary?

Comment: @ma7y For that use case, I would not bother with normalization. Its not too hard to migrate to a normalized schema later if needed.